# Regex to modify Google Drive shared file URL

Tags: regex, url, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a script to convert a regular google drive share URL to a direct download URL. The raw URL looks like this:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/FILE_ID/edit?usp=sharing
```

and needs to be converted to look like this:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID
```

So I'm trying to make my regex, which I'm not very experienced with, to grab the needed text to be deleted/changed. I'm using RegExr to try to create it, but I only get as far as

```
/file/d/
```

I've tried a negative lookahead, but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: which programming language?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**UPDATED ON 23 March 2017**

---

**For PHP:**

```
$link = preg_replace('%https://drive\.google\.com/file/d/(.*?)/.*?\?usp=sharing%', 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=$1', $link);
```

**For Python:**

```
result = re.sub(r"https://drive\.google\.com/file/d/(.*?)/.*?\?usp=sharing", r"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=\1", url)
```

**For Perl:**

```
$subject =~ s!https://drive\.google\.com/file/d/(.*?)/.*?\?usp=sharing!https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=$1!g;
```

**For Java:**

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("https://drive\\.google\\.com/file/d/(.*?)/.*?\\?usp=sharing", "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=$1");
```

**For Ruby:**

```
result = subject.gsub(/https:\/\/drive\.google\.com\/file\/d\/(.*?)\/.*?\?usp=sharing/, 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=\1')
```

**For C#:**

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"https://drive\.google\.com/file/d/(.*?)/.*?\?usp=sharing", "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=$1");
```

**For R Language:**

```
~gsub("https://drive\\.google\\.com/file/d/(.*?)/.*?\\?usp=sharing", "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=\\1", subject, perl=TRUE);
```

**For Javascript:**

```
result = subject.replace(/https:\/\/drive\.google\.com\/file\/d\/(.*?)\/.*?\?usp=sharing/g, "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=$1");
```

**For TCL:**

```
regsub -linestop -all {https://drive\.google\.com/file/d/(.*?)/.*?\?usp=sharing} $subject "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download\\&id=\\1" result
```

**for Oracle:**

```
result := REGEXP_REPLACE(subject, 'https://drive\.google\.com/file/d/(.*)/.*?\?usp=sharing', 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=\1', 1, 0, 'c');
```

**For C++:**

```
wxString ;
wxRegEx regexObj(_T("(?p)\\Ahttps://drive\\.google\\.com/file/d/(.*?)/.*?\\?usp=sharing"), wxRE_ADVANCED);
regexObj.ReplaceAll(&subjectString, _T("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download\\&id=\\1"));
```

**For Groovy:**

```
Matcher regexMatcher = subjectString =~ /https:\/\/drive\.google\.com\/file\/d\/(.*?)\/.*?\?usp=sharing/
String resultString = regexMatcher.replaceAll('https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=$1');
```

**For PostgreSQL:**

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(mycolumn, $$(?p)https://drive\.google\.com/file/d/(.*?)/.*?\?usp=sharing$$, $$https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=\1$$, 'g') FROM mytable;
```

**For VisualBasic.NET:**

```
Dim RegexObj As New Regex("https://drive\.google\.com/file/d/(.*?)/.*?\?usp=sharing")
ResultString = RegexObj.Replace(SubjectString, "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=$1")
```

**For Delphi XE:**

```
Dim RegexObj As New Regex("https://drive\.google\.com/file/d/(.*?)/.*?\?usp=sharing")
ResultString = RegexObj.Replace(SubjectString, "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=$1")
```

**For PowerShell:**

```
$regex = [regex] 'https://drive\.google\.com/file/d/(.*?)/.*?\?usp=sharing'
$result = $regex.Replace($subject, 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=$1')
```

**For Xpath:**

```
fn:replace($input, "https://drive\.google\.com/file/d/(.*?)/.*?\?usp=sharing", "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=$1")
```

**For VBscript:**

```
Dim myRegExp, ResultString
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Global = True
myRegExp.Pattern = "https://drive\.google\.com/file/d/(.*?)/.*?\?usp=sharing"
ResultString = myRegExp.Replace(SubjectString, "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=$1")
```

If you need a different language just let me know! :)

Comment: You forgot Ruby, R, Logo and C#  :)

Comment: I don't see no Logo!!  ;)

Comment: +1 for multi-language-roundhouse-kick answer :-D But will we ever figure out which language was requested..

Comment: @donfuxx I guess not!

Comment: +1. Now just add Basic, Pascal, ALGOL, COBOL, Excel, Fortran, Go!, and Assembly, and Logo, and I'll mail a bouquet to the postal address of your choice.

Comment: @aliteralmin I will !!! But please don't send a bouquet, Ill get in trouble with my wife...send a bottle of wine! :)))))

Comment: I'll send the wine and then the flowers a few hours after that. Make sure she's drunk when they arrive.

Comment: @Tuga: As did you! Awesome answer!

Comment: @aliteralmind I was very surprised...for not receiving the flowers ;)

Comment: Awesome!! Can i have it in prolog? :P

Comment: The PHP version is not working anymore unfortunately. Maybe the URLs have updated since this was posted.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Part of the sharing link changed from `edit` to `view`.  I've updated **all regex versions**, including `php`! Check it out http://ideone.com/GAY9Z2

Comment: @PedroLobito Actually, this is still incorrect. The `drive` part should be `docs` and so on. I can provide you with an example link if you want.

Comment: That would alter the original answer. I've tested the regex with  files from google drive at it works as expected. Please create a new question and I'll be happy to help you.

Comment: It is because the shared URL has been updated since this question was posted. You can confirm this in one minute by clicking the Share button in Google Drive and then `get shareable link`. You will get something like this: `https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eeVLgzhZD7z4MfN9M1XKQOzz0A41ya2QicVEP1OsoQ/edit?usp=sharing` -- as you can see, there are some changes to the structure of the regex. I adjusted your code and the following works: `%https://docs\.google\.com/document/d/(.*?)/edit\?usp=sharing%`

Comment: This only happens if you're inside google **docs** not google drive itself https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive .As I said previously, please open a new question, I'll help you.

Answer (score 6):

You **don't need regex** for that you can complete the url transformation with 2 chained string replace. See for example this (in Java) :

```
String url="https://drive.google.com/file/d/FILE_ID/edit?usp=sharing";
url = url.replace("/file/d/", "/uc?export=download&id=").replace("/edit?usp=sharing", "");
System.out.print(url);
```

**==> The output:**

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID
```

Answer (score 3):

This works in PCRE, in regex101:

- Find what: `^(https:\/\/drive\.google\.com\/)file\/d\/([^\/]+)\/.*$`
- Replace with: `$1uc?export=download&id=$2`
- Try it: http://regex101.com/r/dX1zD2

---

Please consider bookmarking the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the ID with this regex:

```
regex = "([\w-]){33}|([\w-]){19}"
match = re.search(regex,url)
```

33 chars are for normal drives and 19 chars are for team drives
After that you can put the extracted ID in whatever formatted url you make